# HippoCMS RESTFUL API

Tags: hippocms

http://www.onehippo.org/7_8/library/concepts/rest/restful-api-support---content-context-aware-jax-rs-services.html

Can anyone explain more detail than the link?

I have hippo project import to the eclipse. 
and i know the first step is setting up our own REST service is to create an HST mount.
but I don't know where do I configure the following code?

```
<sv:node sv:name="restapi">
<sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
<sv:value>hst:mount</sv:value>
</sv:property>
<sv:property sv:name="hst:alias" sv:type="String">
<sv:value>restapi</sv:value>
</sv:property>
<sv:property sv:name="hst:isSite" sv:type="Boolean">
<sv:value>false</sv:value>
</sv:property>
<sv:property sv:name="hst:namedpipeline" sv:type="String">
<sv:value>JaxrsRestContentPipeline</sv:value>
</sv:property>
</sv:node>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is configured somewhere at

`/hst:hst/hst:hosts/dev-internal/127.0.0.1/hst:root`

(you may have more site nodes in here)

Comment: so, under above mentioned node, there should be at least one of your own site nodes, it should be added as a sub-node of those site nodes

Comment: what's next?  Do I need to modify the source code? Do you know where can i find the detail documentation about it?

Comment: next steps are described here: http://www.onehippo.org/7_8/library/concepts/rest/restful-jax-rs-component-support-in-hst-2.html

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your endpoint using the essential tools:

```
http://localhost:8080/essentials/#/tools/restServices
```

The site's node is generated by rebuilding the project.

It is usually found in the repository at this location:

```
/hst:hst/hst:hosts/dev-localhost/localhost/hst:root
```

I hope it helps.